# Can't send attachment with sendgrid api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sendgrid

I have a byte[] which is a downloaded pdf file in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app.

I'm trying to attach this as an attachment to a sendgrid email message.

```
public async Task SendEmail(byte[] Attachment = null)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

    var msg = new SendGridMessage();

    // I also set the To, Subject, body etc etc

    msg.AddAttachment("test.pdf",Convert.ToBase64String(Attachment) ,"application/pdf","inline");
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

}
```

I get a 'BadReqest' status code.  If I remove the AddAttachment line then the message is accepted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Attachment))
    {
        msg.AddAttachment("test.pdf", stream);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```